Delete from child table on update of parent row with composite foreign key
For reasons outside of my control I am trying to build a graph-like data structure in PostgreSQL. The business requirement is that everytime a node changes, its edges need to be re-computed. Also, there is the possibility of stale reads from the edge creation algorithm, which means I need to guard the edges somehow. So far I've come up with
drop table if exists node;
drop table if exists edge;
create table node (
    id varchar(32),
    version int not null default 1,
    data varchar(32),
    primary key (id),
    unique (id, version)
);

create table edge
(
    id1       varchar(32) not null,
    version1  int         not null,
    id2       varchar(32) not null,
    version2  int         not null,

    constraint normalize check (id1 < id2),
    foreign key (id1, version1) references node (id, version) on delete cascade,
    foreign key (id2, version2) references node (id, version) on delete cascade,
    primary key (id1, id2)
);

However, when I try to update the version of a node, I get into trouble:
insert into node (id, version, data) values ('id1', 1, 'Emmy'), ('id2', 1, 'Marie');
insert into edge (id1, version1, id2, version2) values ('id1', 1, 'id2', 1);
update node set version = version + 1 where id = 'id1'; -- should delete the edge; instead [23503] ERROR: update or delete on table "node" violates foreign key constraint "edge_id1_version1_fkey" on table "edge"

Is there a way to make this work in a single query without having to start a transaction? I kinda wish for an on update delete clause.

"For reasons outside of my control I am trying to build a graph-like data structure in PostgreSQL." - is that just a casual way of introducing a task at work, or do you consider PostgreSQL to be a strange place for a graph? There are pretty mature extensions like Apache AGE and pgrouting exactly for that, and a quick look at the recursive-query tag can show you it's a pretty common thing in this RDBMS and others.

You have a circular reference of FK.... You cannot delete anything with that. As @Zegarek says, use a graph database which is optimized for graph manopulations perofmances or use Microsoft SQL Server that have special graph table for that.... includening shortest path algo....

CREATE EXTENSION age; should fix this issue and turns your PostgreSQL database into a graph database. You have to install the code first

If your goal is to delete any edge referencing the updated node, you can add a delete in a cte, as a part of the same statement: demo at db<>fiddle
with cte as (delete from edge where 'id1' in (id1,id2))
update node 
   set version = version + 1 
   where id = 'id1'; 

Or the other way around, taking version into account:
with cte as (
   update node 
   set version = version + 1 
   where id = 'id1'
   returning version)
delete from edge 
using cte 
where ('id1',cte.version-1) 
   in ((id1,version1),(id2,version2)); 


I was about to introduce the versions into the edge table with an on update cascade clause, but this seems better, as I won't have to worry about edges to dead nodes anymore.

Try use constraint check time.
Set DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED for references (that is default setting?);
Then update or delete in one query. Constraint checks executed at the end of query.
create table edge
(
    id1       varchar(32) not null,
    version1  int         not null,
    id2       varchar(32) not null,
    version2  int         not null,

    constraint normalize check (id1 < id2),
--    foreign key (id1, version1)  references node (id, version) on delete cascade,
--    foreign key (id2, version2)  references node (id, version) on delete cascade,
    primary key (id1, id2)
);
ALTER TABLE edge
    ADD CONSTRAINT unique_reference1_node FOREIGN KEY (id1, version1) REFERENCES node (id, version) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
ALTER TABLE edge
    ADD CONSTRAINT unique_reference2_node FOREIGN KEY (id2, version2) REFERENCES node (id, version) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;

Then update
with u0 as(
 update edge 
   set  version1 = version1 + 1 
 where id1 = 'id1'
)
update node set version = version + 1 where id = 'id1';

Example
blog post
